# performance of basic set theory (intersection, union, exclusion) over large sets of objects, which is faster linq in c# or f#?

Tags: c#-4.0, f#, c#-to-f#

I want to compare two collections of entity framework pocos based on union and intersection. I'm trying to find out if out of the box it would be better to process these sets using f# instead of linq?

Comment: Why don't you just run the relavent benchmark?

Comment: As far as I can tell f# is generally regarded as slower than c# because of immutablility. However internally a set is implemented as a binary tree in f# but linq in c# just does set operations over a normal collection; so looks like f# comes with some set operations optimization already. I was curious to know if anyone has anything more specific than what I have already found out, but as you said I can always run a profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run a profiler -- F# 3.0 supports LINQ, so you should be able to put together a small benchmarking project which uses both LINQ and the standard F# `Set<'T>` and measures the time to complete whatever operations you need (use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for this).

Here's the thing -- the answer to this question is highly dependent on your exact needs, so you need to do a bit of testing to see which is faster for *your* use case. For example, if you create a little benchmark app and find that LINQ (in C# or F# 3.0) is faster by 10ms, do you just go with LINQ because it's faster? Maybe, or maybe not -- it depends on whether that 10ms savings is important for your application; in most cases, it probably isn't, so you should go with whatever solution is easiest to integrate with the rest of your code.

Personally, I'd go with F# 3.0 and LINQ here, because it allows for a very succinct definition, and it may also be faster if EF can offload some or all of the computation to the database server.